# Find the value of $\int \frac {du}{(a-u^2)^2}$

Tags: integration

I am stuck on the following integration problem:

> $\int \frac {du}{(a-u^2)^2}; a$ being a constant.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: There are **three** entirely different problems here! First, easy to forget because it is so small, is the case $a=0$. Then comes $a\gt 0$, which it is notationally more pleasant to deal with by letting $a=b^2$, where $b\gt 0$. And finally there is $a\lt 0$, which is more natural again if we let $a=-b^2$. where $b\gt 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $u=\sqrt{a} \sin{x}$, $du= \sqrt{a} \cos{x} dx$.

Upon doing the substitution, you should get

$$\int \frac{du}{(a-u^2)^2} = a^{-3/2} \int dx \: \sec^3{x}$$

For the latter integral, some trig identities will be needed.

$$\begin{align}\int dx \: \sec^3{x} &= \int d(\tan{x}) \sec{x}\\ &= \tan{x} \sec{x} - \int dx \: \sec{x} \tan^2{x}\\ &= \tan{x} \sec{x} + \int dx \: \sec{x} - \int dx \: \sec^3{x} \end{align}$$

So now

$$\begin{align}2\int dx \: \sec^3{x} &= \tan{x} \sec{x} + \int dx \: \sec{x}\end{align}$$

Can you do the rest yourself?

Comment: Please check my edited question..

Comment: The hint is still valid.  Do you know your trig identities?

Comment: that only works if $a$ is nonnegative, no ?

Comment: @imj: technically, it works for all $a$, but you have to use imaginary numbers for $a<0$.

Comment: @user33640 Actually if $a$ is negative you get $\int\frac{du}{(|a|+u^2)^2}$ and that is standard for $u=\sqrt{|a|}\tan t$.

Answer (score 3):

One more way: expansion in partial fractions:
$$
\frac{1}{(a-u^2)^2}=\frac{1}{((\sqrt{a}-u)(\sqrt{a}+u))^2}= \frac{1}{4a} \bigg(\frac{1}{(\sqrt{a}-u)^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{a}-u)}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt{a}+u)^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{a}+u)} \bigg)
$$
so you end up with four simple integrals. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot for another nice approach to the problem.I have got it.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

HINT: First substitute $u=\sqrt a \sin x$ and then $\tan x =t$
. These will convert it into a standard integral.

Answer (score 0):

Use $u = \sqrt{a} \sin{x}$; we get:

$$
\begin{align}
\int{\dfrac{du}{ (a - u^2)^2}} &= \int{\dfrac{\cos{x} dx}{ (a - a\sin^2{x})^2}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{a^2}\int{\dfrac{\cos{x} dx}{ \cos^4{x}}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{a^2}\int{\sec^3{x} dx} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{a^2} \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \sec{x} \tan{x} + \dfrac{1}{2} \ln{|\sec{x} + \tan{x} |}\right) + C
\end{align}
$$

Where, I used [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed) method to integrate $\sec^3{x}$.

Substitute back the value of $x = \sin^{-1}{ \left(\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{a}} \right)} $